# Is there a way to verify two generic formals are the same type if one is incomplete?

Tags: generics, types, ada

Given a generic parent package:

```ada
generic
    type T(<>) is tagged;
package Parent is
    type Instance is tagged private;
private
    type T_Access is access T;
    type Instance is tagged record
        Thing : T_Access := null;
    end record;
end Parent;
```

is there a way in a child package to ensure a type passed into the child as a generic formal is the same type as (or even a descendant of) Parent.T?  For example, consider the generic child package:

```ada
generic
    type T(<>) is new Base with private;
package Parent.Child is
    type T_Access is access T;
    function Make(Ref : not null T_Access) return Parent.Instance;
end Parent.Child;

package body Parent.Child is

    function To_Parent(Source : T_Access) return Parent.T_Access is
    begin
        -- here is where I need to be able to safely convert 
        -- an access to the complete type to an access to the 
        -- incomplete type.  I can used Unchecked_Conversion,
        -- but that goes south if someone passes in a type to 
        -- Parent.Child that is not the same as Parent.  If
        -- I could know that Parent.Child.T is a descendant of
        -- Parent.T, I could just convert it (I think??).
    end To_Parent;

    function Make(Ref : not null T_Access) return Parent.Instance is
    begin
        return (Thing => To_Parent(Ref);
    end Make;

end Parent.Child;
```

where Base is some base tagged type.  You can use the following as a placeholder:

```ada
type Base is tagged limited null record;
```

I'm looking for a way either compile time or runtime to verify inside of Parent.Child that Parent.Child.T is the same as Parent.T (or even if Parent.Child.T is a descendent of Parent.T.

NOTE:  I am trying to use the parent child package relationship because it allows Child to see into the private section of Parent.

Naively I tried something runtime based like:

```ada
package body Parent.Child is

    -- other stuff

begin
    if Child.T not in Parent.T then
        raise Storage_Error with "Invalid type passed to child package";
    end if;
end Parent.Child;
```

but that just results in a GNAT error:

```
premature usage of incomplete type "T"
```

because Parent.T is incomplete.  The intent here is to create an automatic memory management framework that can be used with incomplete types, so the parent package provides the majority of the functionality while the child package can be instantiated later and add functionality that requires the full type information (like construction/deallocation).  You could then do declarations like:

```ada
type Test is tagged;
package B is new Parent(Test);

type Test is new Base with record
    Thing : Parent.Instance;
end record;

package M is new B.Child(Test);
```

Full set of test code (Please keep in mind that this is both raw and bare to keep it as simple as possible):

```ada
------------------------ Base Package ----------------------------
package Base is
   type Instance is tagged limited null record;
end Base;

----------------------- Parent Package ---------------------------
generic
    type T(<>) is tagged;
package Parent is
    type Instance is tagged private;
private
    type T_Access is access T;
    type Instance is tagged record
        Thing : T_Access := null;
    end record;
end Parent;

------------------------ Child Package ---------------------------
with Base;

generic
   type T(<>) is new Base.Instance with private;
package Parent.Child is
   
   type T_Access is access T;

   function Make(Ref : not null T_Access) return Parent.Instance;
   
end Parent.Child;

with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;

package body Parent.Child is

   -- Used later in code not shown, but needed
   -- and requires Child.T to be complete.
   procedure Finalize is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation
      (Object => T,
       Name   => T_Access);

   function To_Parent is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion
      (Source => Child.T_Access,
       Target => Parent.T_Access);

   -- This is where things get IFFY.  I do unchecked conversions here.
   -- If Parent.T is not equal to Parent.Child.T, then this can go bad
   -- really fast.  If there was a way to verify the types were the same,
   -- then I could safely do this.  Or if there was a way for me to
   -- verify that Parent.Child.T was a descendant of Parent.T, then
   -- I could just convert them without unchecked_conversion.
   function Make(Ref : not null T_Access) return Parent.Instance is
      (Thing => To_Parent(Ref));

end Parent.Child;

---------------------------- Main -------------------------------
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Base;
with Parent;
with Parent.Child;

procedure Main is

   type Test is tagged;
   
   package P is new Parent(Test);

   type Test is new Base.Instance with record
      Thing :  P.Instance;
   end record;

   package PC is new P.Child(Test);

   Thing : P.Instance := PC.Make(new Test);

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Hello");
end Main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got some inspiration from Simon Wright's answer which included a Signature package.  That by itself wasn't enough, but it was a necessary building block for the ultimate solution.  Basically, since Ada doesn't provide a means to verify two generic formal types are the same, I used a separate package to provide that functionality at run time by generating a unique ID for the given type, passing that package to both the Parent and Parent.Child packages, and, inside the Parent.Child body, verify that both instances of the package had the same ID (and thus were the same package).  An example is provided below:

The idea of the signature package led to the following ID package:

```ada
package Type_ID is

   type ID is limited private;
   function "="(L,R : ID) return Boolean;

   generic
      type Item_Type(<>);
   package Unique_ID is
      function Get_ID return ID;
   end Unique_ID;
   
private
   
   -- Implement ID however you wish, just needs to be a unique ID for
   -- each package instantiation

end Type_ID;
```

Then I changed the parent specification to:

```ada
with Type_ID;

generic
   with package ID is new Type_ID.Unique_ID(<>);
package Parent is
   type Instance is tagged private;
private
    -- private stuff
end Parent;
```

And the Parent.Child package spec was updated to:

```ada
with Base;

generic
   type T(<>) is new Base.Instance with private;
   with package ID is new Type_ID.Unique_ID(T);
package Parent.Child is
   
   type T_Access is access T;

   function Make(Ref : not null T_Access) return Parent.Instance;
   
end Parent.Child;
```

Finally, the part where the types are verified to be the same.  Since both Parent and Parent.Child take an instance of Type_ID.Unique_ID(<>), we just need to make sure they are both the same instance by comparing the output of the Get_ID function within the package body of Parent.Child:

```ada
package body Parent.Child is

   -- Other implementation stuff

   use all type Type_ID.ID;
begin
   if Parent.ID.Get_ID /= Parent.Child.ID.Get_ID then
      raise Program_Error with "Invalid type passed to child package";
   end if;
end Parent.Child;
```

Basically adding my own run time type information.

Instantiation of the package then becomes:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Type_ID;
with Base;
with Parent;
with Parent.Child;

procedure Main is

   type Test is tagged;

   package ID is new Type_ID.Unique_ID(Test);
   package P is new Parent(ID);

   type Test is new Base.Instance with record
      Thing :  P.Instance;
   end record;

   package PC is new P.Child(Test,ID);

   Thing : P.Instance := PC.Make(new Test);

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Hello");
end Main;
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous version of this answer missed the fact that Jere needs it to work for [formal *incomplete* types](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-12-5.html#p2.2), which were introduced with [AI05-0213](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai05s/ai05-0213-1.txt?rev=1.8&raw=N).

One of the (main?) use cases for that AI was to make it easier to create signature packages (see the [Ada 2012 Rationale, section 4.3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-4-3.html)) in some circumstances. So, here’s an offering using a signature package - no idea whether it meets the desired use case.

```ada
generic
   type T is tagged;
package Signature is
end Signature;

with Signature;
generic
   type T is tagged private;
   with package Sig is new Signature (T);
package Parent is
   subtype Parent_T is T;
   Instance : T;
end Parent;

generic
   type T is new Parent.Parent_T with private;
   with package Sig is new Signature (T);
package Parent.Child is
end Parent.Child;

with Signature;
with Parent.Child;
package User is
   type Base is tagged null record;
   procedure Proc (Param : Base);

   package Sig_For_Parent is new Signature (T => Base);
   package For_Parent is new Parent (T => Base, Sig => Sig_For_Parent);

   --  this is OK
   type Extension is new Base with null record;
   procedure Proc (Param : Extension);
   package Sig_For_Child is new Signature (T => Extension);
   package For_Child
   is new For_Parent.Child (T => Extension, Sig => Sig_For_Child);

   --  this fails
   type Wrong is tagged null record;  -- not in Base'Class
   package Sig_For_Wrong is new Signature (T => Wrong);
   package For_Wrong
   is new For_Parent.Child (T => Wrong, Sig => Sig_For_Wrong);

end User;

with Ada.Text_IO;
package body User is

   procedure Proc (Param : Base) is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Base_P's Proc called.");
   end Proc;

   procedure Proc (Param : Extension) is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Extension_P's Proc called.");
   end Proc;

end User;

with User;
procedure Test is
   Var : User.Extension;
begin
   Var.Proc;
end Test;
```

---

At the end of the [Rationale chapter](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-4-3.html), the line

> (If this is all too confusing, do not worry, the compiler will moan at you if you make a mistake.)

is certainly true. What I found while playing around with this code is that it’s not very good at telling you what the mistake *is*.

Comment: The question was specifically about incomplete parent type, but `tagged private` is not an incomplete type

Comment: I did try it with an incomplete type, but he compiler wouldn't let me use it with one, which matches with egilhh's comment:  type Test is tagged;
       package P is new Parent (T => Test);
       type Test is tagged null record;
       package PC is new P.Child(T => Test);

Comment: Side note:  what is the etiquette for assigning points to answers?  I feel like I should upvote people who try to help, even if the answer doesn't answer my question, but I don't know if that is the SO way of doing things or if upvote is purely for "this is the correct answer"

Comment: Hovering over the upvote icon shows "this answer is useful", not "this answer is The One". However, I think the answer needs deleting (I had no notion about formal *incomplete* types, having never absolutely needed such a thing - tho I just found a case from 2006 where it would have helped a bit)

Comment: @SimonWright The main place I have used them is for general use memory management because I want to make sure self referential types are usable with the packages.  See my Smart_Access package on github for an example of incomplete type usage.  It has the side effect though of "needing" to have the user supply the deallocation routine since you can't use Unchecked_Deallocation with incomplete types.  See https://github.com/jeremiahbreeden/bullfrog/blob/master/src/bullfrog-access_types-smart_access.ads

Comment: Answer rewritten.

Comment: @SimonWright So I took a stab using the signature package method and I still run into the same problem.  It really stems from 1.  I need the parent package to only use an incomplete type (your example uses a complete tagged type) and 2.  I need the child package to take a full complete type that I can somehow know is the same as the incomplete type from parent.  I tried using the signatures but if I tell the child to use the signature based off of the parent one (which is incomplete), then the child package can't use the type the way I want cause the type is incomplete there now too.

Comment: @SimonWright is there a way I can update my question to clarify anything to help out?  I can add more specific code if that will help?

Comment: @SimonWright I updated my question with a full set of compilable code that uses a bad means of doing the Make.  Hopefully this clarifies it more?  I also updated the previous snippets a bit.  Ulitmately, look at my example main to get an idea for how I want to use parent and child.  I need parent to be created before the full type declaration so I can use a type from Parent in the full type declaration.  Then I use Child to create types of that type (once the full declaration is known).  Mainly because I plan on using Unchecked_Deallocation later on

Comment: @SimonWright followup question.  So the signature package on its own wasn't a solution, but I was able to make another solution work that involved a signature package.  The example in your solution wouldn't work as is, so my question is do I go ahead and mark this as solution since it led me down the path or do I make a different answer up and make sure you get credit for it at the beginning.  Or do I do a combination of both?  I don't know the right SO etiquette.

Comment: I think you should post & accept your own answer and, if you think _this_ one's worthy, upvote it for having been useful - it certainly isn’t the solution, after all

Comment: @SimonWright Okie dokie.  I had already upvoted your answer.  I'll add the solution I found as soon as I can gen up some good example code.

Comment: @SimonWright alrighty, added my answer.  If you feel it is too similar to your answer let me know and I will delete it and just mark yours as the solution.  The big difference was the usage of the runtime ID type, which is what enabled me to verify the two types were the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the parent/child relationship of the generics, you can do something like this:

foo.ads

```ada
generic
   type T(<>) is tagged;
package Foo is

end Foo;
```

bar.ads

```ada
with Foo;

generic
   type T(<>) is tagged private;
   with package Foo_Instance is new Foo(T); --package parameter
package Bar is
 
end Bar;
```

This way, the complete type must exactly match the incomplete type, ie. it cannot be a type extension, thus:

```ada
with Foo;
with Bar;

package Baz is

   type Base is tagged;
   package Base_Foo is new Foo(Base);
   
   
   type Base is tagged null record;
   package Base_Bar is new Bar(Base, Base_Foo);
   
   
   type Extension is new Base with null record;
   package Extension_Bar is new Bar(Extension, Base_Foo); -- fails!

end Baz;
```

Comment: I do need to see the private section of Parent.  I'll update the question to include that requirement.

Comment: One thing I can try playing with is applying Bar's formals to the child package?  Assuming we say Foo is Foo and Bar is a child of Foo, I.E.  Foo.Bar, can Bar see into an instance of the private section of Foo_Instance?  Though I will say passing an instance of a child package's parent into the child feels...weird?

Comment: It feels weird because it's not allowed... ;)

Comment: Indeed!  I just tried it and it yelled at me for 2 things:  1.  trying to use a Parent package instantiation as a formal, which isn't allowed, and 2.  trying to use a private element of the formal Parent instance in Child.  Hmm, any other thoughts?  I can force things from child to parent with unchecked conversions, but then I open myself up to someone instantiating the child package with a different type.  That's where I was trying to see if I could somehow verify the types were the same and raise an exception in the elaboration if not.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way in a child package to ensure a type passed into the
> child as a generic formal is the same type as (or even a descendant
> of) Parent.T?

[Yes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics#Generic_formal_types).

```
Generic
   Type Parent(<>) is tagged private;
Package Example is
End Example;
```

...and...

```
Generic
   Type Descendant(<>) is new Parent with private;
Package Example.Child is
End Example.Child;
```

Comment: Copy/Pasting my comment from another answer: The question was specifically about incomplete parent type, but `tagged private` is not an incomplete type